# Scripting Asterix outbound calls with multiple CallerID?

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterix / FreePBX with a GSM box to send out appointment reminders for multiple companies and wondering, just how much can be scripted in the outbound queue?

I have this that works to place the call, but it isn't setting the `CallerID` - it always shows as the cell number that it is using. I wasn't sure if it is possible to change that on outgoing calls, or if that was just for internal SIP connections, like an inner office phone system:

```
Channel: SIP/4805551234@192.168.1.55 #192.168.1.55 is the GSM box
MaxRetries: 5
Callerid: "Company One" <2095551212>
RetryTime: 300
WaitTime: 45
Context: outboundmsg1
Extension: s
Priority: 1
```

In my `extensions_custom.conf` file, I have this:

```
[outboundmsg1]
exten => s,1,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=5)             ; Set Digit Timeout to 5 seconds
exten => s,2,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=10)         ; Set Response Timeout to 10 seconds
exten => s,3,Answer
exten => s,4,Wait(1)
exten => s,5,Background(outboundmsgs/msg1)         ; "play outbound msg"
exten => s,6,Background(outboundmsgs/how_to_ack)   ; "Press 1 to replay or 2 to acknowledge receiving this message"
exten => 1,1,Goto(s,5)   ; replay message
exten => 2,1,Goto(msgack,s,1) ; acknowledge message
exten => t,1,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => t,2,Hangup
```

- Is it possible to script the `exten =>
  s,5,Background(outboundmsgs/msg1)` in the queue file?

I am asking since there will be multiple companies with appointments at 10 minute increments, so about 48 different combinations per company, so it seems better to script that from the outbound queue than to keep editing the `extensions_custom.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

GSM box send out calls via gsm network. You need have agreement with your gsm operator if you want change callerid. In general it is not possible nor availible.

You should use SIP trunk or e1 connection with contract allowing CID change to get that possibility.